# Why is my CPU performance bad?

Tags: laptop, graphics-cards, processor

Yoga Slim 7 14ARE05 - CPU AMD Ryzen 7 4800 U - 16GB RAM - GPU 512MB ATI AMD Radeon Graphics

I have included the benchmarks in the picture below the render showing both my single core and multi core being 40% and 51% off from the CINEBENCH R23 benchmarks. The test was done only with a browser open and no apps running in the background. My CPU temperature is usually low and stable.

[image]

Comment: This is a Technical support request — Questions asking about troubleshooting hardware or technical support for hardware are off-topic for Hardware Recommendations because the site is here to provide pre-purchase hardware recommendations and to recommend hardware for a specific task, rather than to support existing devices. You may get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).